# square integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have a question about Lebesgue integral.

Let $(S,\Sigma,m)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $f$ be a $\Sigma$-measurable real-valued function.

If $f$ satisfies that $\forall g \in L^{2}(S;m), fg \in L^{1}(E;m)$ then $f \in L^{2}(E;m)$ is hold?

I'm looking for a counterexample.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The condition $\int_S fg\,dm < \infty$ is meant to express $fg\in L^1(S,m)$? Do you know a little functional analysis? If you have heard of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, you should try applying that here.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped.  I will check up about that. Thanks!

Comment: I moved your "forall" to the level of the rest of the text (since I missed it and misunderstood the question).

Comment: Also, to clarify the previous point a little bit, in this context $F[g]= \int_E fg dm$ is a linear functional on $L^2(E,m)$. If it is bounded, then Riesz representation would furnish such an $f$. The Banach-Steinhaus theorem/uniform boundedness principle provides a way to prove that this functional is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be proved using the Baire category theorem. Here is a sketch:

Define $$E_k = \left\{ g \in L^2(S;m) : \int_S |fg| \, dm \le k \right\}.$$
According to your hypothesis, $L^2(S;m) = \cup_k E_k$. It is a straightforward exercise to show that each $E_k$ is closed in $L^2(S;m)$. The Baire category theorem implies that at least one $E_k$ has an interior point.

This means there exists $h \in L^2(S;m)$ and $\epsilon > 0$ with the property that $$\|f-h\|_{L^2} \le \epsilon \implies \int_S |fg| \, dm \le k.$$

If $f \in L^2(S;m)$ and $\|f\|_{L^2} \le 1$, then $\|(\epsilon f + h) - h\|_{L^2} \le \epsilon$ so that
$$\int_S |(\epsilon f + h)g| \, dm \le k.$$ From here you get
$$ \sup_{\|f\|_{L^2} \le 1} \int_S |fg| \, dm \le \frac{2k}{\epsilon}$$
which implies  $g \in L^2(S;m)$.